# How to track clicked links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to track the last "link_to" a user clicked on.  I have found some general ideas of how to do this, but I'm not having any luck getting it to work.
Generally, I have an index list and am trying to direct the link_to on each row to a controller action that will save the :id to a cookie and the user record in the database then redirect to the actual external link.

Im wondering if there is a better way than using "link_to".

This is probably a fairly basic problem but I am brain stuck! 
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can track via AJAX, then redirect to the link all degrading gracefully to no tracking.

Assuming jQuery:

```
# view 
<%= link_to 'Foo', 'whatever', :'data-trackable' => 'id-to-log' %>

# js
$('a[data-trackable]').click(function(){
  $.post('/clicks', { id: $(this).data('trackable') }, function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  });
  return false;
});
```

I think I might be working to hard here, but it's been a while since I've done this and I can't remember how to block until the AJAX request submits and then return. Feel free to edit if you know.

Comment: Thanks Corey, Let me see if I understand; is 'whatever' the URL you are linking to?  Then the js 'data-trackable' will do the tracking?

Comment: Sort of: it's a normal link with a data-trackable attribute, like `<a href="/foo" data-trackable="1">Foo</a>`. The jQuery selector binds a POST ajax request to the click event of any `a` with a `data-trackable` attribute set.