# Is it possible to track clicks on DoubleClick ads in our Rails app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, double-click-advertising

We are currently serving third party DoubleClick ads on our Ruby on Rails app for a client, and they're asking us to deliver specific click data that requires us to internally log clicks to their script tags (so we can associate a user with an ad click). Is this possible?

They seem to have the idea that it is industry standard, but it is tough to find proper documentation without access to any internal DoubleClick tools.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419656/how-to-track-clicked-links)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm dealing with script/Iframe tags from DoubleClick. I've also read on answer on here that mentioned Google doesn't allow external tracking of clicks, to prevent certain issues like people giving their users compensation for clicking. I'm relatively new to the ad-ops, DoubleClick world so I may be asking all the wrong questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty straight forward. I suggest you to create a new super simple project and recreate what im showing below to see that it works and than find a way to drop that into your project (since you haven't provided there any informations/examples).

First, migrate a specific integer to your model, called 'click'. Add association, has_many, belongs_to.

Create a new model ->

```
rails g model Click clickcounter:integer
```

Create a new controller ->

```
rails g controller Clicks
```

inside the ClicksController:

```
def create

        @your_ad = Ad.find(params[:ad_id])

        @click = @your_ad.clicks.new(ip_address: request.ip)

        @click.save

        redirect_to @your_ad.url


    end
end
```

then, add either a form as a wrapper around your add via div, or add a hidden link_to.

Now since your 'Ads' are probably not a model itself, but instead a simple link, you could also simply create the click model with an integer alone and count the clicks without any association. You could link the method to devise (if you are using it) and then add name, ip address at the admin dashboard.

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for the super informative answer. This seems like the best option, though I recently read that Google doesn't allow for third party tracking on DoubleClick ads, so I'll have to do more research on that.